# Android lint is ignoring my lint.xml, skipping checks I am trying to enable

Tags: android, lint

I am trying to use Android lint to check some things about my project. It seems to be ignoring the lint.xml file that I am giving it, making it impossible for me to enable checks.

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04, but I am just calling ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lint from the command line.

I am doing:

```
 $ lint --config GF/lint.xml --html lintCheck.html GF   
 Scanning 7.5.0: .
 Scanning 7.5.0 (Phase 2): 
 ... (and so on) ...
 Wrote HTML report to file:/home/ray/Projects/jj/lintCheck.html
 Lint found 26 errors and 198 warnings
 $
```

The report lists all of the checks that are not enabled. Here is the GF/lint.xml file that I created:

```
 $ cat GF/lint.xml 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <lint>
     <issue id="HardcodedText" severity="error" />
 </lint>
 $
```

Here are the ways I have tried to call lint. In all of these cases, all of the checks say something like:

```
 RelativeOverlap
 Disabled By: Project lint.xml file
```

So, where is the project lint.xml file that it is referring to? I have searched in ~/Android and in all my projects and this file does not appear anywhere else.

RelativeOverlap
Disabled By: Project lint.xml file

What I have tried:

```
 $ lint  --ignore MissingTranslation -Wall --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint  --ignore MissingTranslation -Wall --enable all --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint  --ignore MissingTranslation -Wall --enable Correctness,Security,Performance,Usability --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint  --ignore MissingTranslation -Wall --enable Correctness --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint  --ignore MissingTranslation -Wall --enable RelativeOverlap --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint --enable RelativeOverlap --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint --config GF/lint.xml --html lintCheck.html GF
 $ lint --config GF/lint.xml --html lintCheck.html GF
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What directory is the lint.xml in? (i.e. the "GF" folder is where)? I have a lint.xml file in the same directory as the `src`, `libs`, `build` and `gradle` folders, and it's picked up when I run lint from the command-line.

Comment: Also, does running lint via gradle make any difference? (i.e. `./gradle lint`)

Comment: Should I install the command-line version of gradle to try this? I am using gradle by using Android Studio, not on the command-line.

Comment: The GF directory is my project root, where my src, lib, gradle directories are, and so forth.

Comment: Try putting the `lint.xml` file one directory up - i.e. in the same directory as `GF` is in, rather than in the `GF` folder.

Answer (score 6):

**Configure the lint-options in gradle file for the lint.xml to be picked up**

```
lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // do not ignore warnings
        warningsAsErrors true
        lintConfig file('lint.xml')
    }
```

just put the above lintoptions in the build.gradle file of app folder

And place the lint.xml file in the app folder itself then it will be picked up

here is a screenshot of placement in studio directory:[image]